# edit a post in django

Tags: python, django

I am beginner in django. In the following there is a function for edit a post. I don't know what these two lines do.

```
 id = eval("request." + request.method + "['id']")
    post = Post.objects(id=id)[0]
```

#

```
def update(request):
    id = eval("request." + request.method + "['id']")
    post = Post.objects(id=id)[0]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # update field values and save to mongo
        post.title = request.POST['title']
        post.last_update = datetime.datetime.now() 
        post.content = request.POST['content']
        post.save()
        template = 'index.html'
        params = {'Posts': Post.objects} 

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        template = 'update.html'
        params = {'post':post}

    return render_to_response(template, params, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: [`eval` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval). Basically *evaluates* the expression string, e.g. `eval('request.' + request.method + '["id"]')` might resolve to `request.POST['id']` if the method is POST.

Comment: could you explain more and also explain about second line?

Comment: Wherever you got this code from, you should throw it away immediately. That's a horrible way to get that value. Much better: `getattr(request, request.method)['id']`. Even better: don't do this at all.

Comment: 1. Thanks for sharing this witchcraft with us. 2. Using eval in your project is 90% of the time a sign of poor desing and a lot of future troubles. 3. Your code simple get's the value of the `id` parameter from the request and then searches your database for the corresponding `Post`.

Comment: The second line is not even valid Django. It almost looks like `post = Post.objects.filter(id=id)[0]`, which would try to fetch the post with that id and throw an error if it didn't exist. It would be much better to use `get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)`.